# Reshape table from wide to long - nested keys

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

The goal is to convert this dataframe from wide to long format. The thing that I cannot figure out is how to handle this nested structure. My dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(dwelling=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 nearbypanels2020_250m=c(12, 15, 19, 19),
                 nearbypanels2019_250m=c(22, 29, 18, 12),
                 nearbypanels2020_500m=c(23, 16, 22, 33),
                 nearbypanels2019_500m=c(24, 31, 19, 14),
                 heatpump2020=c(20,25,21,19),
                 heatpump2019=c(19,24,18,12))
```

The desired end result looks like the table below. For clarification: the 'nearbypanels' columns indicate the number of solar panels in a certain year, and radius of a dwelling, which needs to be accounted for. The heat pump variable has no radius indication, so will only get one column in the end result.

| dwelling | heatpump | nearbypanels_250m | nearbypanels_500m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2019 | 19 | 22 | 24 |
| A2020 | 20 | 12 | 23 |
| B2019 | 24 | 29 | 31 |
| B2020 | 25 | 15 | 16 |
| C2019 | 18 | 18 | 19 |
| C2020 | 21 | 19 | 22 |
| etc | .. | ... | .. |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package.  First, though, you would need to regularize the naming scheme so, for example, the year is the last four digits of the name.  I did this by searching for four digits in a row and then moving them to the end of the string.  I did this with `gsub("(.*)(\\d{4})(.*)", paste("\\1","\\3", "\\2", sep=""), names(df))`, which searches for anything (which is saved in `\\1`), then four digits (which are saved in `\\2`) and then anything else (if it exists, stored in `\\3`).  Then, I paste the first and third values together then attach the year at the end.  I use these to reset the names of the data frame. Then, in the `pivot_longer()` specification, you can identify that one of the variables that moves to long format is the year (i.e., the last four digits of the variable name) and that otherwise, the stems (the values before the year) should remain variables (separate columns) in the data frame.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(dwelling=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 nearbypanels2020_250m=c(12, 15, 19, 19),
                 nearbypanels2019_250m=c(22, 29, 18, 12),
                 nearbypanels2020_500m=c(23, 16, 22, 33),
                 nearbypanels2019_500m=c(24, 31, 19, 14),
                 heatpump2020=c(20,25,21,19),
                 heatpump2019=c(19,24,18,12)) 
df %>%
  setNames(gsub("(.*)(\\d{4})(.*)", 
              paste("\\1","\\3", "\\2", sep=""), 
              names(df))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-dwelling, 
               names_pattern="(.*)(\\d{4})$", 
               names_to=c(".value", "year")) %>% 
  mutate(dwelling = paste(dwelling, year, sep="")) %>% 
  select(-year)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   dwelling nearbypanels_250m nearbypanels_500m heatpump
#>   <chr>                <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A2020                   12                23       20
#> 2 A2019                   22                24       19
#> 3 B2020                   15                16       25
#> 4 B2019                   29                31       24
#> 5 C2020                   19                22       21
#> 6 C2019                   18                19       18
#> 7 D2020                   19                33       19
#> 8 D2019                   12                14       12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if I also had a variable in the original df that stays constant over time, such as surface area of the dwelling for example. Could it also be possible to include this one in this script or would I have to merge this later, after this script is done?

Comment: @TvCasteren Sure, if you can exclude those from the pivot in the first argument (which in the code above is `-dwelling`).  If you also want `surface` to stay (just like `dwelling`), do `pivot_longer(-c(dwelling, surface), ...)` and keep the remainder of the pivot call the same.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach which manipulates the year values in long format then pivots wider to the desired format:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 |> 
  pivot_longer(-dwelling) |> 
  mutate(dwelling = paste0(dwelling, str_extract(name, "\\d{4}")),
         name = str_remove(name, "\\d{4}" )) |> 
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   dwelling nearbypanels_250m nearbypanels_500m heatpump
#>   <chr>                <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A2020                   12                23       20
#> 2 A2019                   22                24       19
#> 3 B2020                   15                16       25
#> 4 B2019                   29                31       24
#> 5 C2020                   19                22       21
#> 6 C2019                   18                19       18
#> 7 D2020                   19                33       19
#> 8 D2019                   12                14       12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option with `dcast` + `melt`

```
library(data.table)

dcast(
    melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "dwelling")[
        ,
        dwelling := paste0(dwelling, gsub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", variable))
    ][
        ,
        variable := sub("\\d{4}", "", variable)
    ],
    dwelling ~ variable
)
```

gives

```
   dwelling heatpump nearbypanels_250m nearbypanels_500m
1:    A2019       19                22                24
2:    A2020       20                12                23
3:    B2019       24                29                31
4:    B2020       25                15                16
5:    C2019       18                18                19
6:    C2020       21                19                22
7:    D2019       12                12                14
8:    D2020       19                19                33
```